# Have function loop n times, or until the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, methods, python-class

I have a class I use for scraping a site. It uses the requests library sessions and looks something like this:

```
class Scraper:
    def scrape_page(self):
        """Scrapes the current page"""

        # do something
        self.request_next_page()

    def request_next_page(self):
        """ Finds the 'next' link if available and requests next page"""
```

I want to create a method in the class that allows a parameter that can either scrape `n` number of pages or `all` the pages until there is no next page. The above methods work fine.

However, I don't know of a way to let the parameter be either an integer or just a simple `True` for all. I'm trying to think of the *best* way to do this.

I want something similar to this:

```
    def scrape_pages(self, num):
        """Scrape n number of pages"""
```

Where it can be ran as such:

```
>>>  s = Scraper()
>>>  s.scrape_pages(5)       # scrape the first 5 pages.
```

or

```
>>>  s = Scraper()
>>>  s.scrape_pages(all)     # where all can be True, or anything else that works. I'm not sure.
```

I know I could have two separate functions. Or have an `if` statement to check whether it is `True` or just an integer, and then run a *different* loop depending on the situation (maybe a `for` if integer, and a `while` if something else. I am just seeing if there is a better way to do this?

I noticed the `.split()` method kind of does something similar. Where *maxsplit* can have a limit or not. However, I am not familiar with C to be able to understand how that was accomplished.

Comment: You can use 'wrong' value like 0 as a flag for 'all' - if n=0, then it means all the pages, else - fetch only n pages.

Comment: Use a default argument: `def scrape_pages(self, num=-1)`. You would then simply call `s.scrape_pages()` to get *all* pages. The implementation of the method would then be: `while num != 0: num -= 1; self.request_next_page()`. Using "magic" values like `"all"` to get different behaviour is sometimes considered unpythonic.

Answer (score 0):

This funtionality can be implemented using either a `while-loop` or recursion. `While-loops` tend to be more efficient and easier to read. Also, recursion can raise errors when the number of nested calls is too large.

For the main loop in `scrape_pages` I would do something like this:

```
def scrape_pages(self, num):
    """Scrape n number of pages
       Parameters:
           num: integer or 'all' (fetch all pages)
    """
    if num == 'all':
        num = float('inf')
    else:
        assert type(num) == int
    
    final_results  = ???
    
    while num>0:
        page = self.scrape_page()
        num -= 1
        if [page is empty]:
            break
        # store results
        # ....
    
    return final_results
```

PS. We need to pass `all` as a string or something else, because `all` is a reserved keyword in Python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_all.asp

---

TL;DR:

1. Use `num = float('inf')` to fetch all possible pages.
2. Break the loop when you detect that no more pages are found.

Comment: This is perfect! I never knew you could represent infinity like that. Thank you!